# Losing Post Data with jquery.ajax() type post with php and .htaccess in place

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, .htaccess

I'm using the JSONAP spec to develop an api to process multiple insert statements for PHP.  I've been referencing this link to create my JSON.  http://jsonapi.org/extensions/bulk/#creating-multiple-resources

I submit my form using jquery, and run this code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache:false
    ,contentType:"application/vnd.api+json; ext=bulk"
    ,accept:"application/vnd.api+json; ext=bulk"
    ,dataType:"json"
});

var jsonObject = buildJsonInsert();
//console.log(jsonObject);
$('#remarks').append(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));
$.ajax({
    type: "POST"
    ,url: "/api/STYLE3/"
    ,data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject)
    ,success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
    ,error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
        console.log(ajaxOptions);
    }
    ,complete: function () {
        console.log('complete');
    }
});
```

The JSON is valid that I'm using as I've tested it with http://www.jsonlint.com  The JSON being passed is this

```
{"data":[{"type":"inventory","attributes":{"stock":"4512","date":"2016-02-01","opc":"tb","wd":"E","sze":"030","qty":"1","rem":"TEST","type":"A"}},{"type":"inventory","attributes":{"stock":"4512","date":"2016-02-01","opc":"tb","wd":"E","sze":"035","qty":"2","rem":"TEST","type":"A"}},{"type":"inventory","attributes":{"stock":"4512","date":"2016-02-01","opc":"tb","wd":"E","sze":"040","qty":"3","rem":"TEST","type":"A"}},{"type":"inventory","attributes":{"stock":"4512","date":"2016-02-01","opc":"tb","wd":"E","sze":"045","qty":"4","rem":"TEST","type":"A"}}]}
```

This gets sent to my api.php file which first goes through my .htaccess to cleanup the url.  The .htaccess looks like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/ api.php [L]
```

In my api.php file I check for the appropriate request method from the $_SERVER variable, and the go to process the posted data.  The request method is showing as post, but it doesn't show any post variables.  So I checked the get, request and server query string, and I'm getting nothing from them.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?  I am able to do successful GET requests to retrieve data using the same method.  Just the POST data is being lost here.

api.php:

```
echo 'SERVER:';
print_r($_SERVER);
echo '<br />';
echo 'REQUEST:';
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo '<br />';
echo 'POST:';
print_r($_POST);
echo '<br />';
echo 'GET:';
print_r($_GET);
echo '<br />';
```

Results:

```
SERVER:Array
(
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 578
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/vnd.api+json; ext=bulk
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.8
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
    [HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH] => XMLHttpRequest
    [QUERY_STRING] => 
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [REDIRECT_UNIQUE_ID] => Vt2gbhdbRg0AABIqAhgAAAAb
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /api/STYLE3/
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
    [REQUEST_URI] => /api/STYLE3/
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /api.php
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [UNIQUE_ID] => Vt2gbhdbRg0AABIqAhgAAAAb
    [PHP_SELF] => /api.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1457365102.7973
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1457365102
    [argv] => Array
        (
        )

    [argc] => 0
)
REQUEST:Array
(
    [__unam] => 7639673-14e20c34333-549bc39e-14
    [PHPSESSID] => 9decjei6e70nreuu7028cdojq4
    [_ga] => GA1.2.1543525819.1443120533
    [_asomcnc] => 1
)
POST:Array
(
)
GET:Array
(
)
```

Trying data: jsonObject results in the object being sent as this, but still nothing in get, post, request, server[query_string]

```
data%5B0%5D%5Btype%5D=inventory&data%5B0%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bstock%5D=4512&data%5B0%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bdate%5D=2016-02-01&data%5B0%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bopc%5D=tb&data%5B0%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bwd%5D=E&data%5B0%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bsze%5D=030&data%5B0%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bqty%5D=1&data%5B0%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Brem%5D=JOSE+TEST&data%5B0%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Btype%5D=A&data%5B1%5D%5Btype%5D=inventory&data%5B1%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bstock%5D=4512&data%5B1%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bdate%5D=2016-02-01&data%5B1%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bopc%5D=tb&data%5B1%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bwd%5D=E&data%5B1%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bsze%5D=035&data%5B1%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bqty%5D=2&data%5B1%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Brem%5D=JOSE+TEST&data%5B1%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Btype%5D=A&data%5B2%5D%5Btype%5D=inventory&data%5B2%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bstock%5D=4512&data%5B2%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bdate%5D=2016-02-01&data%5B2%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bopc%5D=tb&data%5B2%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bwd%5D=E&data%5B2%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bsze%5D=040&data%5B2%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bqty%5D=3&data%5B2%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Brem%5D=JOSE+TEST&data%5B2%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Btype%5D=A&data%5B3%5D%5Btype%5D=inventory&data%5B3%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bstock%5D=4512&data%5B3%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bdate%5D=2016-02-01&data%5B3%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bopc%5D=tb&data%5B3%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bwd%5D=E&data%5B3%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bsze%5D=045&data%5B3%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Bqty%5D=4&data%5B3%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Brem%5D=JOSE+TEST&data%5B3%5D%5Battributes%5D%5Btype%5D=A
```

Comment: Could you please try `,data: jsonObject` instead of `,data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject)`? In your case you're sending a string (encoded json) to your server without a name.

Comment: Tried that, I posted the result of the request at the bottom of my question.  Still nothing on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send data with `contentType:'application/json'` then `$_POST` will be empty.

To access it try:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print_r($data);
```